# Find the minimum number in a file using a Bash script

Tags: bash

I have a program that prints a number (the run time specifically) and I have written a Bash script that runs the program with another variable every time. How I can find the minimum of these numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sort` to get the lowest number in a file:

```
sort -n filename | head -1
```

`sort` sorts it numerically, and then `head` gets the first line of `sort's output.

Comment: Please put the code in the question, in a properly formatted code block. I can't read that.

Comment: My file has lines like :
time is : 1234
I want to find the min number of the entire file in this form!